# SELECT distinct rows grouped by column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where i need to pick the latest Id of an employee . The id can be a varchar or int

```
id      mail
-------------
1234    xyz@abc.com
5678    xyz@abc.com
C123    xyz@abc.com
C234    def@abc.com
```

Now, my query result just has to be

```
id      mail
-------------
5678    xyz@abc.com
C234    def@abc.com
```

The logic is, If there is an integer against the mail id, the highest integer has to be picked. If there is no integer, the varchar value can be picked.

Tried

```
select max(id), mail from worker  group by mail
```

But it picks the varchar value when there is a duplicate mail id.

Comment: Do you have any other column that you can order by to determine the latest, like an insert date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the isnumeric value and ROW_NUMBER to select the right value.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id VARCHAR(10), mail VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @T VALUES 
    ('1234', 'xyz@abc.com'),
    ('5678', 'xyz@abc.com'),
    ('C123', 'xyz@abc.com'),
    ('C234', 'def@abc.com')

SELECT id, mail
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        mail,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                mail
            ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(id) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, id) ELSE 0 END DESC,
                id) AS RowNum
    FROM @T
    ) T
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The output yields

```
id         mail
---------- -------------
C234       def@abc.com
5678       xyz@abc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is:

```
select MAX(t.id), t.email 
from ( 
   select * from Emails where ISNUMERIC(id) = 1 
      union
   select * from Emails where ISNUMERIC(id) <> 1 and email not in 
                              (select email from Emails where ISNUMERIC(id) = 1)
) as t
group by t.email
```